# Output data between parentheses to text file

Tags: batch-file, output, extract, parentheses

I have a list of data and only want what's within the parentheses to be output to `.txt` file.

Example data list:-

> Example (Data1) here
>   Example (Data2) here
>   Example (DATA3) here
>   Example (Data4) here

Example output txt file content:-

> Data1
>   Data2 
>   Data3   **   *in lower case if possible also*   **
>   Data4

Currently I use Excel but have to use a delimiter (space bar) then go to another tab, highlight the data and select option to find and replace ( and then ) with nothing.

Does anyone have a script or can advise how to go about this?

Comment: There are no brackets `[`/`]` but parentheses `(`/`)`. Anyway, what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Note, this is not a site to request code for free. But as it's quite simple:

```
(for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %a in (in.txt) do @echo %a)>out.txt
```

If you want to use it in a batchfile, use `%%a` instead of `%a` (both times)